# parse json Object in javascript getting undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I got response in json format but i m facing problem to how to parse it below is my code

```
var jsonValue = JSON.stringify(response);
```

after alert jsonValue i got

```
[
    ["vlue1", 18, "ram", "xmy"],
    ["value2", 21, "abc", "xyz"]
]
```

How to parse it in JavaScript?

Comment: it is array within  array, simply iterate over it.

Comment: yes you got right json array... its a correct one

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by "parse". Reconstructing the stringified object? Can you tell us what you're expecting?

Comment: yeah got it..Its array within array.Okay i will parse it.Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
```

[You can see it explained here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

[Here you can check if it is supported in your target browser.](http://caniuse.com/json)

Answer (score 0):

**stringify()**

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a value to JSON, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

**parse()**

> The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON, optionally transforming the value produced by parsing.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var data = [
    ["vlue1", 18, "ram", "xmy"],
    ["value2", 21, "abc", "xyz"]
];
for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){
    var tem_arr = data[i];
    for(var j = 0;j < tem_arr.length;j++){
        console.log(tem_arr[j]);
    }
}
```

`JSON.stringify` turns an object in to a JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string.

`JSON.parse` turns a string of JSON text into an object.

**EDITED**

```
var data = '[["vlue1", 18, "ram", "xmy"],["value2", 21, "abc", "xyz"]]';
data = JSON.parse(data)
for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){
    var tem_arr = data[i];
    for(var j = 0;j < tem_arr.length;j++){
        console.log(tem_arr[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got individual character. data is a String

Comment: use JSON.stringify() and then iterate over it

Comment: var data = JSON.stringify(response); i written this but still got individual character

Comment: Sorry you should use JSON.parse()

Comment: after use this i got error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h