# Cannot Parse Data From JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create a JSON and populate it with some data. The data is a bit complex so I would like to have its "title", "name" and "value".

My issue is that I am not able to get the content from the JSON I created and getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o" error message. However, if I just pass the json variable to console.log() I can see all the objects contained in the variable.

Please see the code below:

JSON

```
var json = [
    {"title":"rice",
        "value":{
            "carb": 44.5,
            "fat": 0.1,
            "cal": 205,
            "prot": 4.3
        }
    },
    {"title":"buckwheat",
        "value":{
            "carb": 20,
            "fat": 1,
            "cal": 92,
            "prot": 3
        }
    },
    {"title":"potato",
        "value":{
            "carb": 50.5,
            "fat": 0.5,
            "cal": 225,
            "prot": 5.9
        },
    }
]
```

JS

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj[0].title);
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` should be called to turn a string representation of a json object into an actual javascript object.  The `json` variable is already a javascript object.

Comment: You don't have any JSON in your question. Just use `console.log( json[0].title );` without trying to parse it first (although I recommend also renaming your variable since the name `json` is misleading)..

Comment: You also have an extraneous comma after the value object inside the object with title "potato".

Comment: @LinuxDisciple Note that a trailing comma in an object is valid in Javascript (but not JSON), so it should still work find if he doesn't try parsing it.

Comment: As suggested the json variable name is misleading. It's a javascript object (an Array of Objets) but not a JSON. Try to stringify instead of parsing your object HTTPS://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Possible duplicate of duplicate: [parse json Object in javascript getting undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706833/parse-json-object-in-javascript-getting-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand your question but

```
JSON.parse()
```

As first parameter takes some String, text value, converts and returns it as JSON object. Since you have one - you can populate it with your data.

Answer (score 0):

Your json data is not valid.

[Valid Example](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=49148a358b59b67129709cddfebc1926)

You can press f12 in Chrome or Mozilla and look console. You can find what is wrong with your JS code.

```
[
  {
    "title": "rice",
    "value": {
      "carb": 20,
      "fat": 1,
      "cal": 92,
      "prot": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "buckwheat",
    "value": {
      "carb": 20,
      "fat": 1,
      "cal": 92,
      "prot": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "potato",
    "value": {
      "carb": 50.5,
      "fat": 0.5,
      "cal": 225,
      "prot": 5.9
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just didn't understand how do I get any data without a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your var "json" is already a javascript object. Just add a semicolon to it and fix the one error (comma after `"prot": 5.9}`) :

```
var obj = [
    {"title":"rice",
        "value":{
            "carb": 44.5,
            "fat": 0.1,
            "cal": 205,
            "prot": 4.3
        }
    },
    {"title":"buckwheat",
        "value":{
            "carb": 20,
            "fat": 1,
            "cal": 92,
            "prot": 3
        }
    },
    {"title":"potato",
        "value":{
            "carb": 50.5,
            "fat": 0.5,
            "cal": 225,
            "prot": 5.9
        }
    } ];
```

You can simply get the values with:

```
console.log(obj[0].title);
```

If you want to parse json, save your data in string format.